# How can I return a column-major iterator for a numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, iterator

`ndarray` objects in `numpy` have a `flat` property (e.g. `array.flat`) that allows one to iterate through its elements. For example:

```
>>> x = np.arange(1, 7).reshape(2, 3)
>>> x
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> x.flat[3]
4
```

But how can I return a column-major 1D iterator, so that the example above returns `5` instead of `4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way, but it seems that simply

```
array.T.flat
```

will give the result I'm looking for. Although I wish there was some appropriate method that I could specify with `order='F'`, which would be easier to understand at a glance.

Comment: This is pretty clean and efficient.

Comment: Second @user2357112 's comment. This method seems very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1**

You can use `.ravel('F')` to have column major order and then index -

```
x.ravel('F')[3]
```

Sample run -

```
In [100]: x
Out[100]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])

In [101]: x.ravel('F')[3]
Out[101]: 5
```

This will create a copy of the entire array before selecting elements -

```
In [161]: np.may_share_memory(x, x.ravel())
Out[161]: True

In [162]: np.may_share_memory(x, x.ravel('F'))
Out[162]: False
```

As such this may not the most memory efficient one. For a better one, let's move onto another approach.

---

**Approach #2**

We can get the row and column indices from the column-major ordered index and then simply index into the array with it -

```
x[np.unravel_index(3, np.array(x.shape)[::-1])]
```

Sample run -

```
In [147]: x
Out[147]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])

In [148]: idx = np.unravel_index(3, np.array(x.shape)[::-1])

In [149]: idx
Out[149]: (1, 1) # row, col indices obtained in C order

In [150]: x[idx]
Out[150]: 5
```

There isn't any copying or flattening or ravel-ing here and uses just an indexing and as such should be efficient both in terms of memory and performance.

Comment: That builds an entire copy of the array, though. (`ravel` only copies if it needs to, but if you use it like this, it needs to.)